# pipe size to my shower

Tags: water, water-pressure

We are re-doing our shower in the house - we are adding a multi-component system to the shower including a hand held sprayer and jet sprayers.  The bathroom is on the second floor.  The water pressure to the shower system is pretty poor and dinky right now and the contractor wants to change the pipes at the shower level to 3/4 inch from 1/2 inch.  Will that make a difference?  Does he not need to go all the way back to the main line rather than just behind the shower?  How else can I get better pressure to the shower?

Answer (score 1):

You will need 3/4 as a supply for the 3/4 at the shower to do any good.  If you are talking pex, then the 3/4 would be mandatory because inner diameter of pex is smaller than copper.  I'm guessing you have 1/2 copper as your main?